# Algorithm for fast data/time coverage check

Tags: database, algorithm, code-coverage

I am working on a database containing ~50 million rows, each holding a timestamp and a value. The timestamps of the stem from a scope of about 3 years, but sometimes there are timeframes missing in between, ranging from 10 minutes of data lack to several weeks. I want to find these gaps, to see how well the data covers the recording period, and am now looking for a suitable algorithm to do so.

What I have been trying is to start with the oldest record and then go to the next earlier record and so on, until the most recent record is reached. If the gap between two neighboring records is higher than a certain treshold time, then it is counted as a gap. However, this requires the algorithm to check every single record, which takes a lot of time.

This is why I want to ask if there is a more efficent way, possibly heuristic way, of doing this? The data is in MySQL, in case thats relvant.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean "date/time" in your title, rather than "data/time"?

Comment: I mean it as in "how well does the data I have cover the time span I am looking at". Sorry, not a native English speaker ;)

Comment: You should post your code so that we can help you improve it.

Comment: Do you have an index on the date field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just how long does it take to look at 50 million rows? A few minutes? If you're spending time trying to optimize this process, which one would assume you're going to run very infrequently, you're wasting your time. You have an algorithm that's simple and works reliably. Why are you wasting your time trying to improve it?

But let's say you want to improve it because for some odd reason you're running this thing many times. Do you know where your bottleneck is? Unless your comparison function is completely idiotic, the bottleneck is most likely to be in the database access. Not much you can do about that, unless you run your query to get the data in sorted order and output to a text file. Then you can rip through the text file. If you're doing this many times, reading from the sorted text file will be a whole lot faster than querying the database for a sorted result every time.

But you can't reliably avoid the need to look at every transition to determine if there is a gap. Sure, you can use a binary search algorithm to find ranges where there are definitely gaps, but that algorithm can't always identify ranges where there aren't gaps. You *might* be able to come up with an algorithm that, on average, reduces the complexity of searching for gaps, but that algorithm will be complex. So complex that you probably won't be able to prove its correctness.

Stick with the simple, provably correct algorithm. If you need to speed things up, convert your data to an intermediate form that's faster to read.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your response. Maybe I am doing something wrong here, but for me it takes several hours to do that. I do

Comment: 1) select the oldest record 2) find the next younger record 3) calculate the timely distance 4) set next record as working record 5) repeate 2-5 until end is reached. I implemented the algorithm in python, maybe thats why it is so slow?

Comment: @paho Your method is seriously non-optimum. You can get all of the records in order with a simple SQL query like `"Select * from table_name order by timestamp_field_name"`. Then you can rip through them quickly, although it will take a bit of time for the query. With such a large data set, you might have to use a streaming approach. I'm no mySQL expert, so I don't have any specific advice.